# `Docker build` cannot pull base image from private docker registry that requires client certificate in docker 23

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

**Pretext**
I have been using a private docker registry that has been setup to require a client certificate in addition to the normal credentials (username/password). The setup on the server was verified to be working with docker (pre-23 versions), microk8s (containerd), curl, nuget, etc. so I'm pretty sure there should be no problem with my registry.

**Problem description**
Since docker was updated to version 23, buildkit has been the default build engine, and since then `docker build` has stopped working for me. Every time I try to run `docker build .` in a build context with my old Dockerfile (which has `FROM myregistry.com/myimage:tag` as the first statement), docker always return this error:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: myregistry.com/myimage:tag: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden
```

Meanwhile, I can still use `docker login myregistry.com` with my credentials or `docker pull myregistry.com/myimage:tag`. And when I have pulled the image, `docker build` will gladly use it, but it cannot pull the image by itself.

**What I have tried**
I have tried following this document https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/configure/#setting-registry-certificates and create a new TOML file (`~/.config/buildkit/buildkitd.toml`) with these configurations (all certs and keys are in PEM format):

```
debug = true
[registry]
  [registry."myregistry.com"]
    ca = ["/path/to/certs/ca.pem"]
    [[registry."myregistry.com".keypair]]
      key = "/path/to/certs/client.key"
      cert = "/path/to/certs/client.pem"
```

And then create a new builder with

```
docker buildx create --bootstrap --use --config ~/.config/buildkit/buildkitd.toml --name new-builder
```

In `docker buildx ls` output I can see that the new builder is now being used (the one with the asterisk).

Comment: As a temporary workaround, setting the environment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` works. If you want to keep using the new buildkit engine, setting `BUILDKIT_NO_CLIENT_TOKEN=1` also works. Refer to https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/1613 for more details.